# Markov Chain Reversibility and Stationary Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A librarian has three books, labelled $i$ =1,2,3. Everyday, the librarian picks a book i with probability $p_i$ (regardless of where it is on the shelf). By the end of the day, they return it to the shelf one position to the left of where it was previously (unless it was already the leftmost book, in which case it is put back where it was).

(a)Make Xn be the order of the books at the beginning of day n (before a book is selected that day). Show that (Xn,n≥0) is a reversible Markov chain with equilibrium distribution $\pi_{ijk}$ proportional to $p^2_i p_j$.

(b)Suppose that $p_i$ = i/6 and initially the books are in order 123.  Find the expected amount of days until the books are again in this order

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried. part (a) should be clear if you review the definition of reversibility. For part (b) you can use a general formula for the expected return time to a state in aMarkov chain. Also, please render questions on this site using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: sorry would you mind explaining what you mean by part a) should be clear by the definition of reversibility. How do prove it?

Comment: The definition of reversibility requires $\pi(x) p(x,y)=\pi(y)p(y,x)$ to hold for all states $x,y$. Now just check this with the proposed equilibrium measure and the given transition rule.

Comment: so for example go from 123 to 213, when i check the reversibility condition it doesn't hold

Comment: It does hold- see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

To check the reversibility condition $\pi(x)P(x,y)=\pi(y)P(y,x)$ there are just two types of transitions to consider: Swapping the first two books, and swapping the last two:
$$\pi_{ijk} \, P(ijk \,,\, jik) =(Cp_i^2 p_j)\, p_j=(Cp_j^2 p_i)\, p_i=\pi_{jik} \,P(jik \,,\, ijk) $$
$$\pi_{ijk} \,   P(ijk \,,\, ikj)=(Cp_i^2 p_j)\, p_k=(Cp_i^2 p_k)\, p_j=\pi_{ikj} \, P(ikj \,,\, ijk)$$

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. Can you perhaps explain how you arrived at the stationary distribution?

Comment: $\pi$ was given in the question. If it was not given, you could obtain it e.g. by solving the linear equations in the definition of reversibility together with the constraint that the total sum equals $1$.